# Term PaaS application

Tags: cloud, definition, saas, difference, paas

I have allready read many articles about the difference between SaaS and PaaS, but sometimes they are very blurred.

So I'm a bit confused and want to know whether my following sentences are correct.

PaaS provides runtimes and allows the developer to deploy applications.
Now the developer wants to offer the application to his customers.

My understandig is that an application hosted in a PaaS is called PaaS application.
The way how the customer consumes the software is called SaaS.

But sometimes there is the term SaaS application, which doesn't fit into my understanding.
I think SaaS does only mean that a consumer gets a software from a provider, so it can't be called SaaS application.
In our case, the providers PaaS holds the application, so it must be called PaaS application.

I hope somebody can help to clarify my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think your sentences are quite correct.

For me a PaaS is a special subtype of SaaS, because the "P is also a S".
Every *platform* is always also a piece of *software*. ;-)

I would define it from the consumer perspective:

- **PaaS** provides services to build/compose own **solutions or services**,
  and is used by own/other **software**
- **SaaS** provides services to **build/realize business processes** and is used (more or less) by real **users**

Example:

- Office365 is a SaaS for me as a user
- Microsoft would perhaps call Office365 a SaaS application
- Office365 is build upon Azure-PaaS
- Azure provides the i.e. SQL-PaaS application to built Office365

**You should ask who is yor consumer?**

Answer (score 0):

May be the given examples will give you a bit more clear picture - paas and saas

1. Salesforce, Windows azuzure, Amazon web services are best examples of PAAS
2. freshdesk, greythr, intercom are good examples of SAAS

Comment: Please try to  explain a bit more what do you mean